# Converting base 2 (binary) number to base 10 not working quite well in python

Tags: python, list, binary, decimal

I'm trying to write a code which converts a binary number to a base 10 one, but there seems to be a small problem with it (either logic or calculation). I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I searched that on the net but didn't find the solution I wanted (there were other ways of converting it, apparently). How can I fix my code? I think I'm so close to the actual result...

**My Code**

```
num = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]

string = ''
for i in num:
    string += str(i)

print(string)

def bin_to_dec(binary):
    decimal = 0
    for i in range(len(binary)):
        if string[i] == '1':
            decimal += 2 ** (len(string) - i - 1)
        if i == len(string) - 1:
            decimal += 1

    return decimal

print(bin_to_dec(string))
```

**Expected Output**

```
4294967286
```

**Code Output**

```
4294967277
```

I'm new to python, please don't go harsh on me :D

Comment: Your input is wrong. It should be `num = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]`. And then you should get rid of the last `if` statement.

Comment: It's easier to compute this if you iterate over the string in reverse - then the power is simply `2 ** index`.  In fact you can reduce it to a one-liner: `sum(2 ** i for i, b in enumerate(reversed(string)) if b == '1')`

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thanks! I've never used ```enumerate``` yet, that's why :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this code will give you the correct result.

```
    decimal = 0
    for i in range(len(binary)):
        if binary[i] == '1':
            decimal += 2 ** (len(binary) - i - 1)
    return decimal
```

I'm not sure how you calculated your expected output but by my maths it is wrong. the maximum value with this number of bits is 4294967295, and your number takes away 19, leaving you with 4294967276, which i'm pretty sure is the right answer.

Comment: oh I see... I don't know why I wrote ```string``` instead of ```binary```, I somehow ignored it unintentionally... Thank you!